# Spring cloud gateway routing with path

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to write a gateway routing with a path (route everything to [www.example.com/foobar/](http://www.example.com/foobar/)), but the '/foobar/' part is ignored, and everything is routed to [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/))

My RouteLocator configuration is:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator myRouteLocator(final RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route(route -> route.path("/**").uri("http://www.example.com/foobar"))
            .build();
}
```

When I call the service with `http://localhost:8080/myApiCall`, cloud gateway forwards the call to `http://www.example.com/myApiCall` instead of `http://www.example.com/foobar/myApiCall`.

If I call my service as `http://localhost:8080/foobar/myApiCall`, the resulting call is `http://www.example.com/foobar/myApiCall`, so it works correctly in this case.

Based on some debugging, my final URL is created here:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/v3.1.3/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/RouteToRequestUrlFilter.java#L88
Where only the host is used, the path is omitted from the configuration.

My used versions:
spring-cloud-gateway: v3.1.3
spring-core: v5.3.20

I have thought about just using a rewritepath filter to always append the `/foobar/` part - but isn't there a better way?

Comment: Don't use `/**` in the path predicate, use `/{segment}` instead

Comment: Hey @HuuPhuongVu
What do you mean by "/{segment}"? Is this some documented function of Cloud Gateway that I didn't find, or you just mean that I shouldn't just route from "/**"?